# How to use stop loss with ATR (Pine Editor)

Tags: pine-script

I hope you can help me understand what I may be doing wrong. I want to set a stop loss to be at the previous candles low minus the atr before the trade is made. This condition doesn't seem to be met and it will always hold the stop until "exitRule" is satisfied. This results in bad trades and I'm not sure why. Any tips are welcome. Thank you for your time.

```
if longEntry
    strategy.entry('Buy', strategy.long)
    stopLoss = ta.lowest(low, 1) - ta.atr(1)[1]
    strategy.exit('Stop Loss', 'Long', stop=stopLoss)
    strategy.close('Exit', when=exitRule)
```

I tried using stopLoss = ta.lowest(low, 1) - ta.atr(1)[1]
I thought this would refer to the day the trade was made but it seems to be a moving value.

Answer (score 0):

first thing is the ID of your position ("Buy") is different from the exit ID. Also you've to specify variables, you can't make single-time calculation inside the if statement. Try something like this:

```
var float stopLoss = 0
last_atr = ta.atr(1)[1]
last_lowest = ta.lowest(low, 1)

if longEntry and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry('Buy', strategy.long)
    stopLoss := last_lowest - last_atr
    strategy.exit('Buy', stop=stopLoss)

plot(stopLoss)
```